# Cant't install any new packages or run upgrade, missing final newline

Tags: apt, upgrade

If I try to run `sudo apt upgrade` or install a new package on Ubuntu 16.04.3 I get following error:

```
Selection previously unselected package smartmontools.
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 files list file for package 'mount' is missing final newline
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

I get following output if I run `tail /var/lib/dpkg/info/mount.list`

```
y;^▒_▒'▒#▒▒ܭ▒Z▒▒▒H▒"*QJ▒▒C▒&▒/[.`▒(Y7-▒n$1%▒▒W\▒▒7VTK▒▒j▒b▒27[▒S▒P▒▒E{▒▒▒O▒▒|▒.r▒▒l2▒e▒D▒▒y▒▒Wwʋ▒▒▒▒{▒▒6▒ٟ▒▒^\!▒l▒jiܠ▒▒\4媗B▒j%▒▒▒D4SɾMD▒▒Kb▒▒N'▒Œ▒9=▒}3▒▒▒i▒ͮ▒Wbz▒▒<▒uTiäǧ▒E.▒lj/▒ع\▒j▒**r▒pGjnWa,▒▒u▒▒▒W▒▒▒[▒),q▒ZN-[▒c▒▒▒O/▒▒▒2▒▒7▒▒=v)<y4▒S{▒▒▒7▒▒m^8ʹl<▒▒T▒▒$▒/śR▒▒▒▒[▒Τ▒▒▒?▒(ˬR▒▒▒˩/Qg5▒OQ▒▒2/{ؒ▒▒4x~▒Fy▒=▒"▒▒▒s▒▒9],▒s▒<▒}>▒r▒▒6▒▒▒t3▒▒▒kw▒; ▒ȢY}ʜ▒&▒,▒▒2▒▒e|Dl▒▒▒▒}H9     ▒O▒▒▒pbC"Pȱ▒▒▒▒a▒Z'▒▒c▒▒I▒I>▒
▒▒▒▒▒▒6G▒/▒▒▒▒9:1^▒4▒▒▒▒$▒n▒▒&^o▒^k}▒▒ݏK▒▒▒>▒▒2▒xw▒+O▒▒▒▒Z▒I=▒ɿ▒b▒j_▒&▒gZ>
               E▒▒|▒▒oI▒▒S▒=▒▒ُ▒wG▒Ry▒>▒:▒▒~     ▒▒ҭ=▒▒e▒^{▒▒B▒▒]▒▒P)▒z▒1▒d▒.g▒▒▒I▒▒▒▒_▒"▒▒1▒c▒k▒c▒)IyLя▒M▒>▒▒-▒▒▒x▒v0ם▒▒▒Gh`Í▒ͯ▒%▒▒p▒▒▒
                                                      ▒▒▒ۙ?▒_(▒▒▒_▒b▒!▒▒▒▒▒?▒I▒j1▒▒▒c|x▒.▒N▒\Zj▒▒Qe▒dX▒ ▒b`▒▒▒▒▒▒I▒▒c▒Q▒▒"q[▒X▒
&▒▒▒▒▒t(▒$▒(▒`▒.▒4▒{▒▒9'O▒I0▒▒cQ▒O2J▒▒▒▒▒f▒I▒▒"▒▒ ▒G6▒~▒ODۋ▒`▒Z▒F▒Q
nRK▒▒
Pɓ4ܛ\;▒▒]▒
Չ▒"▒s2▒Wf5▒▒'H▒▒▒(#.▒Ĕ%¤▒▒▒▒▒Ty▒G▒q▒I~izQ<xu▒ȓ▒!▒:▒i?ő▒▒g%▒▒▒i▒U
                                                                ▒"▒=41▒E/▒%▒pf▒s@J▒e▒$n▒
%▒▒-▒@,▒8▒\▒g▒▒▒?▒0▒~-▒▒▒&O▒DǪ▒M^▒▒▒t▒▒\▒▒▒▒▒&}b▒▒X▒o▒▒▒▒dq▒R▒▒m▒▒FyI▒m▒sIn▒
4▒y▒zh▒▒VTW9_7d,▒M▒▒▒B
                      6▒▒▒▒▒
▒!▒c▒~QH▒[▒▒▒▒▒e▒^?▒▒T▒j1c]RNL▒^/▒ޖ▒ϗ'z▒▒g▒▒▒▒VLqN▒K▒▒▒xt9▒▒▒6▒▒3C▒▒▒b▒.
▒▒▒▒y▒~▒U;_▒J▒▒2,\▒▒▒M▒▒4▒!
▒▒▒BtD .u▒▒                ▒▒▒?▒x▒q▒▒$H▒'▒<▒6▒o▒▒:▒N▒`▒Y▒{O▒▒▒.▒eX
           ▒D2$▒▒▒p▒▒Co▒-8Ѐ▒!▒r▒▒g▒▒z\{▒;CSP&*Ay▒/▒P▒▒)▒r$▒▒{m▒[▒▒XK▒/y▒.▒0▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒6m@Fa▒b▒](dD+▒"\▒�q▒▒\▒▒V▒В▒▒$▒▒TdZ}▒{▒▒G▒▒▒ћ▒▒[▒k▒"m▒G▒i8▒%▒▒p▒▒VH▒▒▒▒8▒O▒▒(▒▒J▒▒rx▒n▒]6▒▒|o▒▒
▒
▒
▒▒▒▒▒▒%4▒0▒▒z~▒h▒▒▒Ԛr"+,▒▒h▒J▒P▒▒a/▒▒8]ԣL(▒3xFy▒=E▒D▒▒h▒▒▒6n▒8▒▒E▒▒▒S▒▒▒
?/~▒ʹ▒Ȝ'▒N▒▒1▒▒▒+d=▒B▒'|i
                         ▒A?▒xk▒*▒▒▒▒/gj&▒▒:▒/▒▒▒n▒▒/▒Ga,▒▒ह▒▒▒x▒
▒▒{▒#▒▒ntn▒k▒R▒k▒@"xd2T▒#T▒▒▒▒▒w▒\▒F▒0▒+MB▒▒▒▒
535H6/(▒▒▒▒▒f(▒9▒g▒▒▒w▒V▒Y▒w1▒pN▒1l▒Oq▒1▒▒▒▒O▒<▒t▒▒▒    ބ▒▒_▒▒▒V0▒▒▒▒\▒▒d▒▒?▒?▒O▒▒▒3lP<C▒&▒.▒▒  ▒i7cy▒▒▒c"▒▒▒▒AY        `▒?▒5bQ▒7▒Rgr▒5m/▒2X▒▒0ĮJ▒▒▒▒▒ѷO▒E▒▒▒gϏ8▒~jr▒▒>▒8▒{▒▒▒▒▒▒qN▒%p▒▒ܙ▒Du3%▒a▒▒▒▒+▒"▒▒k▒▒g▒
                                              ▒!'▒▒�▒H▒▒▒p▒Z8▒~<▒:Wk▒▒T▒▒PʋWxf]▒⦘BcPޘ▒x▒▒t▒▒U▒�jsK▒▒4▒+▒▒H,▒e▒h▒▒qí▒d▒▒ ▒`▒▒Sq▒▒▒▒▒4uJ▒▒▒TMݯߟ▒▒j(▒▒ǝ▒▒jXf{▒▒▒▒㍉▒`5▒▒▒▒g▒^▒O▒
x▒v▒▒▒▒1▒3X▒▒▒G#▒B▒▒y▒▒F▒*▒DW▒▒H▒Ѹ▒
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Please add output of ` tail /var/lib/dpkg/info/mount.list` to the question.

Comment: @N0rbert I have edited my answer.

Comment: Probably need to file a bug report

Comment: Sounds like this: [Many files in /var/lib/dpkg/info/ corrupted; how to recover](https://askubuntu.com/questions/490587/many-files-in-var-lib-dpkg-info-corrupted-how-to-recover) - I'd be interested to know how it happened

Comment: Good question unfortunately I did not work on the system before. I just need to clean up a bit.

Answer (score 2):

Try to install `mount` package manually:

```
apt-get download mount
sudo dpkg -i mount*.deb
```

You can check other problematic file-lists with the following command:

```
grep --color='auto' -P -n "[^\x00-\x7F]" -r /var/lib/dpkg/info/*.list
```

(may give some false-positives with unicode characters such as `ő`, but you got the idea).